# powershell -match string with if it has one of a certain character. I.E lastname_firstname not match lastname_firstname_middleinitail

Tags: regex, powershell, active-directory, match

I'm trying to match strings that only have one underscore.  Match is currently finding both lastname_firstname and lastname_firstname_middleinitail.  I only want to return lastname_firstname and exclude everything else.

I've tried  `-match "._." ".(_)." "._{1}" -like "*_*"` has the same problem.

Here is the part of my code that has -match

```
$newUsers = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "CN=Users,DC=atlantic,DC=county" -Filter {WhenCreated -ge $date7DaysAgo} | Where-Object {$_.name -match "._."}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to perform a part of the filtering with LDAP to reduce the dataset, making your code more efficient. `(name=*_*)` will only search for users which's `name` attribute contains at least one `_`, excluding those without one.

For the second layer of filtering, [`^[a-z]+_[a-z]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/4l1O9Y/1.) would ensure that the names only have one `_` but also have only characters from `a` to `z`, if you need to be more inclusive, i.e. names could have `0` to `9`, you could use `^[a-z0-9]+_[a-z0-9]+$`.

```bash
$daysAgo = [datetime]::UtcNow.AddDays(-7).ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss.0Z')

$getADUserSplat = @{
    SearchBase = 'CN=Users,DC=atlantic,DC=county'
    LDAPFilter = "(&(WhenCreated>=$daysAgo)(name=*_*))"
}

$newUsers = Get-ADUser @getADUserSplat |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^[a-z]+_[a-z]+$' }
```

Comment: Thanks '^[a-z]+_[a-z]+$ worked perfectly.  Is there an advantage to using [datetime]::UtcNow.AddDays(-7).ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss.0Z').  In my code I'm using 

$days = "7"

# Get the date $days days ago
$date7DaysAgo = $(get-date).AddDays(-$days)

Comment: @Warlord213 there is no advantage, thats how the filter `{WhenCreated -ge $date7DaysAgo}` gets translated to behind the scenes by the AD Provider. The problem is that with the filter you currently have, you wouldn't be able to also add `name -like '*_*'`, it would throw an error. Thus I need to convert the filter to LDAP Syntax so the AD Module doesn't throw an error ;)

Comment: I see what your saying.  I tried using -like at one point to see if it would produce a different output but I'm only using -match now.  Also you help me understand that the modifiers like + and ? need to be used in conjunction with with a range.  That is what was tripping me up before.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Warlord213 for reference, if you wanted to use `Filter` instead of `LDAPFilter`, the syntax would be `"whenCreated -ge '$daysAgo' -and name -like '*_*'"` but same way as I did here, the `$daysAgo` should have that format `yyyyMMddHHmmss.0Z`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me complement [Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76184436/45375), which is the best solution to your specific problem, with an answer to the *general* problem implied by your question's title:

How can I **test if string contain *exactly N* occurrences of a given character**, for N >= 0?

```bash
$char = '_'
$n = 2
@(
  'no underscore',
  'one_underscore',
  'two_underscores_here'
  'three_underscores_are_here'
) | 
  Where-Object {
    # Matches only 'two_underscores_here'
    ($_ -replace "[^$char]").Length -eq $n
  }
```

Note:

- **[`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator)**  `"[^$char]"` uses a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) to in effect remove all characters *other* than the one of interest, leaving a string composed of instances of the character of interest only, whose length then implies the occurrence count.
- For **at-most-N / less-than-N** and **at-least-N / more-than-N** logic, replace `-eq` with `-le` / `-lt` and `-ge` / `-gt`

---

**Alternative**, with a direct call to the [`[regex]::Matches()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches) .NET API:

```bash
$char = '_'
$n = 2
@(
  'no underscore',
  'one_underscore',
  'two_underscores_here'
  'three_underscores_are_here'
) | 
  Where-Object {
    # Matches only 'two_underscores_here'
    ([regex]::Matches($_, "[$char]")).Count -eq $n
  }
```

---

For the sake of completeness: **if N equals 1 or N is *fixed* or you need *at-least-N* logic and you don't mind the added complexity of more sophisticated [regexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)**, you can also use **[`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch)** as follows:

- For simplicity, the character of interest is *hard-coded* to `-` in the following examples.
- For easier adaptation to other characters it is enclosed in `[...]` even for the positive match, even though with `_` that's not strictly necessary.

```bash
@(
  'no underscore',
  'one_underscore',
  'two_underscores_here'
  'three_underscores_are_here'
) | 
  Where-Object {
    # Matches only 'one_underscore'
    $_ -match '^[^_]*[_][^_]*$'
  }
```

Example with a ***fixed* N value > 1**; note that the required explicit repetition of parts of the regex (somewhat mitigated by the `\1` backreference) makes this impractical for larger N values:

```bash
# N = 2
@(
  'no underscore',
  'one_underscore',
  'two_underscores_here'
  'three_underscores_are_here'
) | 
  Where-Object {
    # Matches only 'two_underscores_here'
    $_ -match '^[^_]*([_])[^_]*\1[^_]*$'
  }
```

- For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/JrZbhc/1).

**At-least-N** logic greatly simplifies the regex:

```bash
# N >= 2
@(
  'no underscore',
  'one_underscore',
  'two_underscores_here'
  'three_underscores_are_here'
) | 
  Where-Object {
    # Matches 'two_underscores_here' and 'three_underscores_are_here'
    $_ -match '_.*_'
  }
```

The edge case were **N is 0** is easiest to handle, because all you need to is to ensure that there's *no* `_` present, which is easy to do with `-notmatch`:

```bash
# N = 0
@(
  'no underscore',
  'one_underscore',
  'two_underscores_here'
  'three_underscores_are_here'
) | 
  Where-Object {
    # Matches only 'no underscore'
    $_ -notmatch '[_]'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Where-Object {$_.name -match "_.*?_"}` will check if there are 2 or more underscores in the input string, but you want the opposite. So, you can reverse the output of `$_.name -match "_.*?_"` by using a NOT operator :

```
Where-Object { !($_.name -match "_.*?_") }
```

Comment: Note that PowerShell has negated operator variants: `$_.name -notmatch '_.*?_'`. Worth mentioning: The question is underspecified in that regard, but conceivably the intent is to match only strings with _exactly one_ `_`, in which case you'd also have to rule out those that have _none_.